# Firing a javascript function from a dynamically created button

Tags: html, button, onclick

**Updated code and issue:**
I am creating a test harness for my RPC server.  Currently it consists of a page which immeadiately fires off an AJAX request to retrieve all functions on the server.  Once that is returned it creates a list of buttons so I can click to test.  Eventually I will add dialog boxes to test parameter passing to the functions but currently I want to just fire off the basic request when I click the button. The issue I am seeing is that the onclick function is always firing the last function in the list presumably because when the click is fired key is set to the last value in the array. I thought to pass button.innerHTML value but that too suffers that the last button.innerHTML is that of the final key.

What do I need to do to fire off the action correctly?

Here is the business end of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.jsonRPC.setup({
    endPoint: '//api.localhost/index.php'
});

$.jsonRPC.request('getExampleData', {
    params: [],
    success: function(result) {
        for (var key in result.result) {
            console.log(key+' => '+result.result[key]);

            var button = document.createElement('button'); 
            button.innerHTML = result.result[key]; 
            button.onclick = function() { callRPCFunction(result.result[key]); return false; } 
            var foo = document.getElementById("page"); 
            foo.appendChild(button); 
        }
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
});

function callRPCFunction(target) {
    $.jsonRPC.request(target, {
        params: [],
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment to `element.onClick` will not work until the `element` is added to the `DOM`. You may call `element.onClick(callRPCFunction(result.result[key]));` after `foo.appendChild(element);`. That might work!

You may use jQuery's `live()` here, it was created for these purposes:

`$(element).live('click', callRPCFunction(result.result[key])`